# Error while upgrading to latest version of PDFTron

Tags: ios, ipad, pdftron

I was using the previous version of PDFTron for iOS (6.5.4a). Now since a new version is available so I decided to upgrade to 6.7.2 . I am using static framework. Now when I open a pdf, go back from it and again try to open the same pdf the app crashes with the following error :

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type trn::Common::Exception: Exception: 
 Message: Bad image dimensions
 Conditional expression: inout_size.x>0 && inout_size.y>0
 Version    : 6.7.1.53210N
 Filename   : PDFDraw.cpp
 Function   : CalcDevMtxFromSize
 Linenumber : 239
```

Comment: Is that full error message, there should be more information, such as the function name, file and line number.
Also, can you reproduce using one of the SDK sample projects, or does this occur only in your project?

Comment: Yes this is full error message.Nothing else is given. I am unable to reproduce this in sample projects but the sample projects are using dynamic framework. I am trying to work with Static frameworks.

Comment: @Ryan The complete error message is as follows:                            
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type 
    trn::Common::Exception: Exception: 
    Message: Bad image dimensions
    Conditional expression: inout_size.x>0 && inout_size.y>0
    Version    : 6.7.1.53210N
    Filename   : PDFDraw.cpp
    Function   : CalcDevMtxFromSize
    Linenumber : 239

Comment: I have updated my question with all the required details. Kindly help asap.

Answer (score 0):

There have been improvements to image reading, and this exception should no longer occur. Please update to the latest version. If the latest version doesn't help, then we would need access to the file in question.

Comment: I am using the latest version 6.7.3 (60035). It is still occurring. How would you access the file ?

Comment: Either post here, or open a ticket here https://www.pdftron.com/support/reportproblem.html and attach. If the file is too large to attach request an upload link in the ticket.

Comment: Can you tell me under what condition can this error occur?

Comment: Did you post/send the file so we can check? If you need a NDA first then definitely contact PDFTron support.